# visual studio Solution ip (remote debug)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-embedded-compact

i have a working solution, that is running on a windows Embedded Compact framework on a remote arm processor. (visual studio 2012)
the debugging is done by sending the project over the local network.

We are trying to get this debugged on multiple devices and so need to manualy set all the ip adresses every time we try to use a different end device.

is there an easy way to automaticly change the ip in the entire solution by only changeing the ip in 1 location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i was trying is not available,
so i can eather copy paste the ip on all projects, of remoddel my solution